# Creating php pages in wordpress and assigning them to wordpress pages

Tags: customization, pages, single

/I have few pages in my wordpress site which should contain some php code. For example news page.

In my front-page.php I have a while which loops trough all posts and prints few news.

In my news site I want to do the same.

I have already tried using

```
<?php /* Template Name: news */ ?>
```

But this is only the template, so only my html works here, php while did not output any data.

What is the best approach to achieve this (as simple as possible) ?

EDIT:

In simple words, how to create a static php wordpress page.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to add the PHP to the template file itself, or in the content editor?

Comment: PHP code should be between php tags. use `get_header` and `get_footer` functions.

Comment: @WebElaine Imagine you have your web site, in the navigation you press on the "News" . And you open news.php from your template directory and display it in your site. In the same way that you create e.g front-page.php . The templating thing i wrote bellow is not what i am looking for it was just an example of me not finding the right way (in a way) :)))

Comment: @MahdiY which planet are you from, did you even read the question ?

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for `WP_Query` or something similar, to grab a group of posts and display them within your news page template.

Answer (score 1):

MahdiY just explain that you can use PHP in your template like that

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: news
*/

get_header();
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php
                echo "This is PHP";
            ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```